# Silverlight isn't works in Windows Safari

Tags: windows, silverlight, safari

I try to call a method in javascript it works in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera and Mac Safari,but in Windows Safari isn't works.

my code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("my javascript method");
```

I was reading about this and found this is a SilverLight and Safari bug.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it seems that you want to create new window. You can achieve this using java script. so you can find a piece of javascript code that will work in all the browser and pass that javascript code inside the method eval as shown below.

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("alert('kind of Script')");
```